# Php server call works but still receive an error message

Tags: php, sql

Here is my code.  The error message says the problem is in the `while` loop statement.

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in line 136

```
/*  We need to create a connection to SQLServer08 */
$serverName = "**************\main, 1433"; 
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"****", "UID"=>"****","PWD"=>"****");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);

$EventID = $_GET['id'];

/*  Excecute a Query   */   
$tsql = "SELECT *
        ,convert(int,LEFT(starttime,2)) as StartHour
        ,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,StartTime),4,2) as StartMinute
        ,convert(int,LEFT(endtime,2)) as EndHour
        ,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,EndTime),4,2) as EndMinute 
        FROM Event where EventID =". $EventID; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql); 

/* Retrieve and display the results of the query. This is an array-recordset, so we loop thru the results */

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
```

The weird part with all of this is that my code will still compile. Even when I change something from the client's perspective, it makes the change in the database and lists the new information. I just need the error to go away!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Your query can be incorrect; 
Try to process query $tsql into mysql;
Because sqlsrv_query returns a statement resource on success and FALSE if an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

See the example 1 from the [PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php)

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)";
$params = array(1, "some data");

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

You need to check $stmt for false (use === or !== instead of == or !=) before using it!